# Program For Arranging Windows (in Windows 7 - 8)

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-8

I currently use WindowSpace and Sizer for arranging my windows in Windows 7 and Windows 8. I want to know if there are any programs specifically for window manipulation (resizing, moving, arranging and saving positions). For example, I have a setup of multiple programs that I use when programming and having to set up everything after a reboot is tedious. Are there any programs out there that do these kind of things?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[AutoSizer](http://www.southbaypc.com/autosizer/) might be what you're looking for. It can resize, position, and always-on-top windows by class or title.